# How to properly use Meteor.connect() to connect with another Meteor server

Tags: meteor

My new client code in /client/main.coffee

```
Xingyun = Meteor.connect "localhost:3000"
System = new Meteor.Collection "system", Xingyun
Meteor.subscribe "system"
```

In my original meteor code, the "system" is published and the "system" collection contains one doc. I can verified it with "System.find().count()".

On my new client browser, "System.find().count()" always return 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try `Xingyun.subscribe "system"`

Comment: You are right! I should read the doc more carefully at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_connect