# Meteor Admin Microservice via DDP

Tags: meteor, ddp

I am trying to build an Admin panel that will connect to another apps database and have the ability to change the data stored there.

```
var remote = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
var ServerAItems = new Mongo.Collection('items', { connection: remote  });

Meteor.startup(function() {
  console.log(remote);
  remote.subscribe('smallBatchProducts', function(item){
});
  console.log(ServerAItems.find().count(), 'test');
 });
ServerAItems.find().count(); //returns 0
```

I have looked at [Meteor: No docs from remote collection in template helper when connecting two apps via DDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053822/meteor-no-docs-from-remote-collection-in-template-helper-when-connecting-two-ap) and [Connect two Meteor applications using DDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358526/connect-two-meteor-applications-using-ddp) , but still can't figure out how to interact with the data and give the client access to it. The publication on localhost:3000 is smallBatchProducts.

I'm planning to have Flow Router handle the routing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just put your console.log into the `onReady` callback.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  remote.subscribe('smallBatchProducts', {
    onReady: function(){
      console.log(ServerAItems.find().count(), 'test');
    },
    onError: function(err) {}
  });
});
```